# I want to print the data taken from the server with the interface design I want ( I'm having trouble showing and listing in the interface)

Tags: android, json, android-studio, layout, programmatically-created

I am pulling data from the server. I can do whatever I want. However, I cannot list the data with this design.

Can you show me a method example to do this?

I have been working for a very long time but I had to ask.

Thanks for your answer.

This is what I can do :( programmatically, but not what I want

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(strJson);

int i = 0;
while (jsonarray.length() > i) {

    final String result_json_text = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("demand_title");
    final String content = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("demand_content");
    String imager = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("demand_image");
    final String id = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
    String slug = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("slug");

    //LİST VİEW kısmı

    Button upadtebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guncelle);
    Button silbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sil);

    //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);

    TextView valueTV = new TextView(context);
    TextView value = new TextView(context);

    valueTV.setText(id + " - " + result_json_text + "\n");

    value.setText(content + "\n");

    ImageView postimage = new ImageView(context);
    postimage.setMaxHeight(200);
    Picasso.get().load("http://sabcanuy.pythonanywhere.com" + imager).into(postimage);

    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    // SİL BUTONU

    Button updateBtn = new Button(context);

    updateBtn.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    updateBtn.setText("Güncelle");

    updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, updatePost.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button btnTag = new Button(context);
    // BUTONA BOYUT VERME EKSİK

    btnTag.setWidth(50);
    btnTag.setText("Sil");
    btnTag.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    btnTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DeletePost(id);

            try {
                Toast.makeText(context, "sleeeeeeep", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Thread.sleep(250);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent refresh = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
            finish();

            Toast.makeText(context, "TEKRAR YÜKLENİYOR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    TextView val = new TextView(context);

    val.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    val.setWidth(40);

    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(postimage);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(value);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(btnTag);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(updateBtn);

    Log.d("FOR_LOG", result_json_text);
    i++;

}

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: first check if anything is throwing exception. Attach a debugger on this line e.printStackTrace(); or check your logcat.

Comment: Why don't you use RecylerView?

Comment: @faranjit Your response led me to another answer. This is cardview. maybe my question was very funny for someone who had finished school or for someone who knew the job. I started to work in androide for 2-3 months. I have a project. I'm learning through this project. I work hard for that. Normally I wouldn't ask, but all my solutions and ideas were exhausted. Thank you very much.